# List to TreeSet conversion produces: "java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
List<MyClass> myclassList = (List<MyClass>) rs.get();

TreeSet<MyClass> myclassSet = new TreeSet<MyClass>(myclassList);
```

I don't understand why this code generates this:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: MyClass cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

MyClass does not implement Comparable. I just want to use a Set to filter the unique elements of the List since my List contains unncessary duplicates.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does `MyClass implements Comparable<MyClass>` or anything like that?

If not, then that's why.

For `TreeSet`, you either have to make the elements `Comparable`, or provide a `Comparator`. Otherwise `TreeSet` can't function since it wouldn't know how to order the elements.

Remember, `TreeMap implements SortedSet`, so it has to know how to order
the elements one way or another.

You should familiarize yourself with how implementing [`Comparable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)
defines *natural ordering* for objects of a given type.

The interface defines one method, `compareTo`, that must return a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer if this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the other object respectively.

The contract *requires* that:

- `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))`
- it's transitive: `x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0` implies `x.compareTo(z)>0`
- `x.compareTo(y)==0`  implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))` for all `z`

Additionally, it *recommends* that:

- `(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))`, i.e. "consistent with `equals`

This may seem like much to digest at first, but really it's quite natural with
how one defines total ordering.

---

If your objects can not be ordered one way or another, then a `TreeSet` wouldn't make sense. You may want to use a `HashSet` instead, which have its own contracts. You are likely to be required to `@Override hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` as appropriate for your type (see: [Overriding equals and hashCode in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java))

Comment: MyClass does not implement Comparable. I just want to use a Set to filter the unique elements of the List since my List contains unncessary duplicates.

Comment: Use a HashSet then. It doesn't try to sort the elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't pass an explicit `Comparator` to a `TreeSet`, it will try to compare the objects (by assuming they are `Comparable`). And if they aren't `Comparable`, it cannot compare them, so this exception is thrown!
`TreeSets` are sorted sets and require either objects to be `Comparable` or a `Comparator` to be passed in to determine how to sort the objects in the `Set`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the set to remove duplicates, used a `HashSet`, although that will shuffle the order of the objects returned by the `Iterator` in ways that appear random.
But if you want to preserve the order somewhat, use `LinkedHashSet`, that will at least preserve the insertion order of the list.

`TreeSet` is only appropriate if you need the `Set` sorted, either by the Object's implementation of `Comparable` or by a custom `Comparator` passed to the `TreeSet's` constructor.