# Returning a SortedSet

Tags: java, collections, treeset, sortedset

When I run the following code:

```
  Student student1 = new Student("Billy", 13);
  Student student2 = new Student("Bob", 12);
  Student student3 = new Student("Belle", 11);
  Student student4 = new Student("Barry", 10);
  Student student5 = new Student("Brian", 10);
  Student student6 = new Student("Bane", 13);
  Collection<Student> students = new HashSet<Student>();
  students.add(student1);
  students.add(student2);
  students.add(student3);
  students.add(student4);
  students.add(student5);
  students.add(student6);
  for(Student student : students)
  {
    String name = student.getName();
    System.out.println(name);
  }
```

It will print out a list of names for my student objects. Now I'd like to do them in alphabetical order. I thought it would be as simple as using a TreeSet or SortedSet.

Like this:

```
 Student student1 = new Student("Billy", 13);
 Student student2 = new Student("Bob", 12);
 Student student3 = new Student("Belle", 11);
 Student student4 = new Student("Barry", 10);
 Student student5 = new Student("Brian", 10);
 Student student6 = new Student("Bane", 13);
 Collection<Student> students = **new TreeSet<Student>();**
 students.add(student1);
 students.add(student2);
 students.add(student3);
 students.add(student4);
 students.add(student5);
 students.add(student6);
 for(Student student : students)
 {
    String name = student.getName();
    System.out.println(name);
 }
```

But this just throws the exception:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: helloworld.Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:542)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:238)
    at helloworld.Main.main(Main.java:60)
```

Java Result: 1

I have added a compareTo method in the student class too:

```
 public int compareTo(Student other)
 {
   return this.getName().compareTo(other.getName());
 }
```

Comment: Always, always, always post the exception (or compile-time error) when your question involves one. My guess is that `Student` doesn't implement `Comparable`, but we can't tell as we don't have either the exception or the `Student` class...

Comment: You're not reading the javadoc of TreeSet. It says: *The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which constructor is used*. The *natural ordering* part links to Comparable, which your class doesn't implement. And you didn't provide a Comparator. How could a TreeSet compare non-comparable elements?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: helloworld.Student cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
        at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:542)
        at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:238)
        at helloworld.Main.main(Main.java:60)
Java Result: 1        Sorry i am new to all this. This is the exception. So i have to create a comparable method in my class student??

Comment: Don't post important informations only as comment (especially if it is code which can't be properly indented in comment). Instead use [edit] option placed under your question to add this information in your question (with proper formatting).

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2504803/3182664 , and hundreds of other questions (usually involving classes like `Student` or `Employee`...)

Comment: "*I have added a compareTo method in the student class too*" did it help, or you still have same error? Did you add `implements Comparable<Student>` part to your class declaration like described in posted answer?

Answer (score 7):

What do you mean by "order"?  If you mean in the order they were added, then just use `LinkedHashSet`.  If you want some kind of sorting, then you have to describe how `Student`s should be sorted by having `Student` implement `Comparable<Student>` or by providing a `Comparator<Student>`.

If you meant alphabetical order, then you should modify the `Student` class like so:

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
   ...
   public int compareTo(Student other) {
     return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I meant in Alphabetical order

Comment: @Khal What if your Student would have `name` and `surname` Strings and `age` int? How would you like to order it, and how TreeSet should know about it?

Comment: I just really want to pull back the name, nothing else

Comment: I think @Pshemo's point is that you have to specify what you want to sort by _somehow_, Java can't work it out for you when you don't tell it.

Comment: For reasons pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21659849/3182664 , it is generally preferable to use an own implementation of `Comparator` instead of implementing the `Comparable` interface. Exactly because of your introductory question: **"What do you mean by "order"?** - It can be anything. Students simply do **not** have a **natural ordering**.

Answer (score 1):

For Alphabetical order, you have 2 ways.

1. Either alter your Student class by implementing comparable interface.

   **Reason** :- When we add element to TreeSet then for each existing object in Treeset JVM compares current object by calling compareTo/compare method on them and by implementing Comparable interface we are providing compareTo method implementaton.
2. OR- Provide a Comparator object while creating TreeSet i.e

   ```
   Collection<Student> tm = new TreeSet<Student>(new Comparator<Student>() {

       @Override
       public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
           return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
       }

   });
   ```

   Here,I've used anonymous Comparator.Hope this Helps.